# Replacing text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var newValue = $('.TwitterSpot').text().replace('#', 'Blah Blah');

$('.TwitterSpot').text(newValue);
```

My assumption is that it will get all characters or pieces of text that have "#" replace it with Blah Blah.

It is not working? What am I missing?

The end result I want is to get `#tag` and replace it with a link to a link to `twitter.com/#!/search/%23tag`.

Comment: What type of element has the `.TwitterSpot` class?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2xHnt/ -- Works fine for me.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this server side or client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to do it like

```
$('.TwitterSpot').text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(/#/g, 'Blah Blah');
});
```

`.text()` like many other `getter/setter` jQuery functions offers a callback which gets passed in the current value. By returning a new value you can update that string.

Your mistake was not using a regular expression for the `.replace()` function. By doing that you can set the global flag `g`, which makes sure every occurence is matched.

Comment: This needs to also grab the text value of the tag so that it can be added to the url.

Comment: Is there a way of not losing formatting for other elements within .TwitterSpot div?

Comment: @Anicho: there are more elements contained by that div? Uhh that would get a little more tricky then. We would need to get the `.contents()` from the element and find the `TextNode` to modify.

Comment: No issue you got me going in the right direction /#/g worked like a charm. I'll target the element directly within .TwitterSpot instead.

Answer (score 2):

`.replace` takes a regular expression.  To replace all you have to use the global ("g") flag.

`.replace(/#/g, 'Blah Blah')`

Comment: .replace also takes strings. See the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: This needs to also grab the text value of the tag so that it can be added to the url

Comment: Is there a way of not losing formatting for other elements within .TwitterSpot div?

Comment: @pete the type may be string, but it's understood as a regular expression